# creating a block device programmatically in mac os x using iokit framework

Tags: xcode, macos, driver, iokit

As i am a total noob to mac os x programming i am having some problems understanding this.I want to create a block device in mac os x leopard which would act as a normal drive in mac os x and after that i want to define the geometry of that device or drive according to a drive which i created during installation. As i am using xcode and want to do driver development so i am using iokit framework. Can anyone tell me which header files and API`s should i use to accomplish this task. Any help would be appreciated. Please help me!!!
                                                                                Ironhide707.

Answer (score 2):

You want the IOStorage subsystem of IOKit. The easiest way to get started is to create a filter scheme driver: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/MassStorage/08_Media_Example/MS_Media_Example.html

The book "Mac OS X Internals" by Amit Singh also contains some info and an example on this (source available at http://osxbook.com/).